# How do I compare a char array from a class with another char array using the overload == operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, operator-overloading, overloading

I have a class called Airplane with a private data member thats a char array.

```
// char array variable in my class
char* name{nullptr};
```

my goal is to compare for equality this variable and an input variable of type const char [].

my overload function looks like this:

```
bool Airplane::operator==(const char input_name[]) const{
    if (this->name == input_name) {
         return true;
     }
return false;
}
```

By overloading the == operator, I want to be able to do the following:

```
Airplane plane("hello");
if (plane == "hellooo") {
   // do something
}
```

I want to be able to create a class with a text variable like "hello" and then be able to == it to any random text I want to compare equality. Right now my code just doesnt work, it runs and then ends in the console with no errors. basically I need to compare to char arrays, one within the class the overload function is built in, and another given as input by the user. Thank you for any help.

Comment: `char *` is not an array.  Why not simply use `std::string`?

Comment: use `std::string` instead

Comment: If you really do want to use a char* use
if(strcmp(this->name, input_name) == 0)

Answer (score 1):

As @PaulMcKenzie has rightly said, `char*` is not an array.

I suggest using `std::string` instead of `char*` as well as in `overload` as follows:

```
const bool Airplane::operator==(const std::string& str_to_be_compared) const {
    return this->(whatever variable stores the name of the plane) == str_to_be_compared;
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try and update my post shortly with how it goes, thanks.